# Двумерный ArrayList,JAVA

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ArrayList<Integer> inter=new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ar = new ArrayList<>();
inter.add(2);
inter.add(3);
ar.add(inter);

inter.add(44);
inter.add(62);
```

почему,когда я добавляю элементы в лист inter,уже после того,как я добавил `2 и 3` в сам двумерный лист,он автоматически продолжает добавлять `44 и 62` хотя ниже,я нигде не указывал это?т.е. при выводе `System.out.println(ar);` результат будет `2 3 44 62`

Comment: inter - это ссылка на объект. Т.е. по сути адрес места памяти, в котором находится список. И в ar вы добывляете ссылки. Соответственно, объект-то остаётся один и тот же, т.ч. изменяя его, вы увидите изменение, обращаясь к нему по любой ссылке, которая на него указывает. Вам нужно копировать список.

Comment: @КириллМалышев если мне нужно,чтобы например 2 и 3 хранились в 0 индексе ar листа,а 44 и 62 в 1 индексе,что мне необходимо сделать?если ar массив ссылок,если правильно понял

Comment: @Ark, Вам нужно создать еще один объект ArrayList<Integer> , с помощью add() внести в него 44 и 62, и добавить его после добавления объекта inter.

Comment: @GinTasan так уже делал,просто проблема в том ,что все нужные числа хранятся ток в одном листе inter,единственное,что придумал,написал ниже к вашему ответу,но не знаю насколько правильно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы создаете объект ArrayList inter и добавляете в него 2 элемента 2 и 3, потом в ar , как первый элемент добавляете объект inter, т.е. ссылку этого объекта, потом идет добавление 44 и 62, и ar уже через ссылку может работать с пространством памяти , куда ссылается объект inter. Поэтому ar имеет доступ к элементам 44 и 62

UPD:

```
ArrayList<Integer> inter=new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> inter_one=new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> ar = new ArrayList<>();

inter.add(2);
inter.add(3);
inter_one.add(44);
inter_one.add(62);

ar.add(inter);
ar.add(inter_one);
```

UPD: 
Вариант, который предлогал реализовать в комментариях

Comment: есть более "правильный"способ,чем так?:inter.add(2); inter.add(3); inter.add(35);
ar.get(0).add(inter.get(0));
ar.get(0).add(inter.get(1)); ar.get(0).add(inter.get(2));
или приходится каждый раз поэлементно обращаться?

Comment: В основном , в таких вариантах создаются циклы, при помощи которых есть возможность сократить код и повысить производительность

Comment: похоже,единственный вариант только циклами,спасибо!

Comment: Еще смотря что вам необходимо реализовать , советую посмотреть основные коллекции и работу с ними, можно сделать совершенно различные варианты, удачи )